# Using bootstrap form submit using glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, search

I am using bootstrap and in bootstrap navbar i have a search form.

Here is the code:

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="POST"  role="search"  autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
              <input class="typeahead searchField" name="search" id="search" type="text" >
              <label for="search" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="search"></label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
          </form>
```

I am using glyphicon inside the input field. But the button beside the input field is not looking good.

How do i make the search glyphicon act as a button for submitting the form?

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on bootstrap 3, I suppose this is what you want:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="POST" role="search" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="typeahead searchField form-control" name="search" id="search" type="text">
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
```

The icon is placed *within* the `<button>` tag, so that it is displayed in the button.

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/go/CDF3b5fVWg)

Comment: I dint mean that.. i don’t want button only. I want search icon inside the input text field on the right which should act as search button.

Comment: I see. Something like this then: https://www.codeply.com/go/WEqbsf3RMN ?

Comment: Exactly, But how do you submit the form with that search glyphicon?